# Get the length of a `FOR JSON AUTO` result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, json, azure-sql-database

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT tbl.A, tbl.B, tbl.C
FROM MyTable tbl
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This works great and returns the JSON for me to work with. However, I have need to do some pre-processing based on this generated string inside a stored procedure before I return the result.

So how can I get the length of this JSON string before I return it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store the JSON string in a variable, you can then determine the length of the variable.

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @var = (
            SELECT tbl.A,tbl.B,tbl.C 
            FROM MyTable tbl
            FOR JSON AUTO
            )
SELECT
    LEN(@var)
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks!